# Getting 500 Error: Failed to establish a backside connection in Bluemix while accessing application

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I developed a Java Web application with Cloudant DB as service.

It works locally fine with a delay in response maybe because of Cloudant as DB service. So I pushed & deployed my web application into Bluemix to make it fast.

Application were successfully deployed. It will display the welcome page properly. But when accessing page which require DB connection with Cloudant DB to fetch data & display page I am getting the following error:

```
500 Error:Failed to establish a backside connection.
```

Is it a Bluemix problem? How to fix this issue?

Below is the log for your reference

```
2016-01-25T16:40:42.143+0530
[RTR/0]
out
sentimentanalysisprj.mybluemix.net - [25/01/2016:11:10:42 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 0 34438 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0" 108.168.250.155:21535 x_forwarded_for:"49.248.202.187" x_forwarded_proto:"http" vcap_request_id:dca9c24b-6435-4976-6c5d-c11835202c49 response_time:0.013027513 app_id:e01bccb3-3efa-4202-bce7-a17da49d54fd x_global_transaction_id:"943965375"
2016-01-25T16:40:43.262+0530
[RTR/3]
out
sentimentanalysisprj.mybluemix.net - [25/01/2016:11:10:43 +0000] "GET /images/top1.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 0 29721 "http://sentimentanalysisprj.mybluemix.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0" 108.168.250.156:60152 x_forwarded_for:"49.248.202.187" x_forwarded_proto:"http" vcap_request_id:ded26179-0ee3-4b14-6294-403170253efc response_time:0.010754905 app_id:e01bccb3-3efa-4202-bce7-a17da49d54fd x_global_transaction_id:"3113190919"
2016-01-25T16:40:43.264+0530
[RTR/0]
out
sentimentanalysisprj.mybluemix.net - [25/01/2016:11:10:43 +0000] "GET /images/Top3.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 0 35671 "http://sentimentanalysisprj.mybluemix.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0" 108.168.250.153:32835 x_forwarded_for:"49.248.202.187" x_forwarded_proto:"http" vcap_request_id:5fb2e2a0-54f8-4563-6002-30eb02285e9e response_time:0.005390614 app_id:e01bccb3-3efa-4202-bce7-a17da49d54fd x_global_transaction_id:"4246986239"
2016-01-25T16:40:44.608+0530
[App/0]
out
[WARNING ] SRVE0190E: File not found: /favicon.ico
2016-01-25T16:40:44.883+0530
[App/0]
out
[WARNING ] SRVE0190E: File not found: /favicon.ico
2016-01-25T16:40:49.866+0530
[RTR/0]
out
sentimentanalysisprj.mybluemix.net - [25/01/2016:11:10:49 +0000] "POST /login.do HTTP/1.1" 200 41 1794 "http://sentimentanalysisprj.mybluemix.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0" 108.168.250.153:33903 x_forwarded_for:"49.248.202.187" x_forwarded_proto:"http" vcap_request_id:fd67554f-0dcd-4dc6-7411-593e6164c815 response_time:0.006416079 app_id:e01bccb3-3efa-4202-bce7-a17da49d54fd x_global_transaction_id:"1699061361"
```

Comment: Can you please add here the logs for your application? Please run `cf logs <app name> --recent` and update your question with the output

Comment: The logs you posted does not have any error. Please note that the command I suggested above only provides the recent logs, so you have to recreate the issue and immediately run the command so you can see the error.